# Loading Tensorflow saved models using the C Api version2.3

Tags: c++, tensorflow, tensorflow-c++

I have a .pb model file generated by python TF V2.3. When I am trying to load it using the C api it throws the error what(): Invalid GraphDef. Does the current C/Cpp api support loading of models generated by V2.3?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmBp1.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes TensorFlow C API can load .pb model generated with Python TensorFlow 2.3. "What():" error is generated when C_API receives an unexpected value for a parameter. For example, you provide -1 or 0.5 where C_API is expecting a positive integer.